# Extjs 4 nested xml into treepanel

Tags: xml, extjs, extjs4

I have a java webservice I can't modify. It produce xml like :

```
<query>
    <entity TYPE="Location">
        <value TYPE="Id"/>
        <value TYPE="Class"/>
        <value TYPE="Name"/>
    </entity>
    <entity TYPE="Activity">
        <value TYPE="Id"/>
        <value TYPE="Date"/>
        <value TYPE="Duration"/>
    </entity>
</query>
```

I need to put the xml into the treestore, entities will be folder and values as leafs. I tried to describe 2 models with relations :

```js
Ext.define( 'modelEntity' , {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model' ,
        proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'query.xml', //just for tests
        reader: { type: 'xml' , root: 'query' , record: 'entity' } ,
    },
    fields: [
        {  name: 'leaf' ,  type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true} ,
        {  name: 'text' ,  type: 'string', mapping: '@TYPE'}
    ],
    hasMany: { model: "modelValue", name: "value",  }
});

Ext.define( 'modelValue' , {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model' ,
    fields: [
        {  name: 'leaf' ,  type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true} ,
        {  name: 'text' ,  type: 'string', mapping: '@TYPE'}
    ],
    belongsTo: "modelEntity"
});
```

with one treestore and a treepanel :

```js
Ext.define('storeQuery' , {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',   
    model: 'modelEntity',
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        leaf: false,
        children: []
    },
    autoLoad: false
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    store: Ext.create('storeQuery'),
    rootVisible: false
    ......
});
```

Obviously it doesn't work, only entities are displayed, their children nodes aren't. Help me please ! =)

Comment: What if you remove the `leaf` field from `modelEntity`, or set its `defaultValue` to `false`?

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. When I expand one Entity, I load all the entities, again and again !

Comment: It's very simple but impossible with extjs ???

Comment: ...in every case, the store load listener would need to attach leaf:true to child-nodes in order to nest them (the common behavior is, to click some node and then attach leafs on-the-fly). Therefore, A memory store which updates itself via XHR might make sense (just to have some buffer locally, which prevents constant re-loading and also handles the leaf true/false).